# Trying to extract data from Jtable in a method, but finding nothing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel, defaulttablemodel

The problem I am having is when I am trying to find data from the table by making a method and calling that method. It seems that the table doesn't exist, as I am getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Below is the code, model is the `tableModel`.

```
        // @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String s = dropDown.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if(s.equals("9 out of 11")) {
                System.out.println(model.getValueAt(1, 1));
            } else {
                checkScores();
            }
        }
    });

    return panel;
}

public static void checkScores(){
    Object o = model.getValueAt(1, 1);
    int i = ((Integer) o).intValue();
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you don't have any data. JTable indexes are zero-based. If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The JTable has data, and can be manipulated as long as you are not trying to manipulate it from another method

Comment: *"seems that the table doesn't exist as I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"*  That would more likely cause a `NullPointerException` as opposed to AIOOBE.  It has been said before, but a little louder this time.  **For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).**

Answer (score 2):

There is not enough information to be certain, but it *appears* that the `ActionListener` is being called *before* the `TableModel` is fully constructed. Also, verify that all Swing components are being constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).